# SwiftUI: .sheet() doesn't go to the previous view with expected data when dismiss current sheet

Tags: swiftui

As minimal, my code is like below. In `SinglePersonView` When user tap one image of movie in MovieListView(a movie list showing actor attended movies), then it opens the `SingleMovieView` as sheet mode.

The sheet could be popped up as tapping. But I found after close the sheet and re-select other movie in `MovieListView`, the sheet always opened as my previous clicked movie info aka the first time chosen one. And I could see in console, the `movie id` is always the same one as the first time. I get no clues now, do I need some reloading operation on the dismissal or something else?

And is it the correct way to use `.sheet()` in subView in SwiftUI, or should always keep it in the main body, `SinglePersonView` in this case.

```
struct SinglePersonView: View {
  var personId = -1
  @ObservedObject var model = MovieListViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView() {
      VStack() {
        ...
        MovieListView(movies: model.movies)
        ...
      }
    }.onAppear {
      // json API request
    }
  }
}

struct MovieListView: View {
  var movies: [PersonMovieViewModel]
  @State private var showSheet = false

  ScrollView() {
    HStack() {
      ForEach(movies) { movie in
        VStack() {
          Image(...)
          .onTapGesture {
              self.showSheet.toggle()
          }
          .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
              SingleMovieView(movieId: movie.id)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be only one .sheet in view stack, but in provided snapshot there are many which activated all at once - following behaviour is unpredictable, actually.

Here is corrected variant

```
struct MovieListView: View {
    var movies: [PersonMovieViewModel]
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var selectedID = ""         // type of your movie's ID

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView() {
            HStack() {
                ForEach(movies) { movie in
                    VStack() {
                        Image(...)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.selectedID = movie.id
                                self.showSheet.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                SingleMovieView(movieId: selectedID)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! I should place ```.sheet``` out of  ```ForEach``` loop, and assign the id in the loop to ```State``` property. That fix my code issue, thank you! I found I could put ```.sheet``` after scrollView and get same effect, so is there any different of putting ```.sheet``` after Stack View or Scroll View?

Comment: Sure, I also change the question title to align with the question.